# Not able to download any file in php on windows8 and ie10?

Tags: php, windows-8, download, internet-explorer-10

i have some file which generated dynamically and downloaded, code is running with no problem with other browser even on window 7 ie 10 working fine but not able two download file in window 8 ie10. i have also try to download simple text file  with header text/plain which is also not downloading. it shows downloading prompt with the file name in which downloading code is there not the name i specified and nothing happen on clicking save in ie 10.working in other.

```
<?php 
echo "this is sample text";
header('Content-type: text/plain');

//open/save dialog box
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="sample.txt"');

?>
```

Comment: post codes.. make things clearer

Comment: In order to get answers, you need to ask a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was window 8 bug with IE 10 only that was fixed later :)